# Why are some @username's deleted when posting comments?

Tags: support, feature-request

When I use @username in a comment, sometimes it is deleted when I post, and deleted again when I try to edit it back in.

A case in point is @mac in this thread:

[How to fix a racked/sagging exterior wood entry door?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32600/how-to-fix-a-racked-sagging-exterior-wood-entry-door#comment46478_32600)

Does this reflect a setting that the user has configured on their account? or ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is automatically done by the server when the `@name` is redundant, such as when you try to reference the OP in a comment (though once there are a few others in the comment stream, it's no longer redundant and the server once again allows the `@name`). They will still get the notification in these situations. You will know this is going to happen when `@name` doesn't autocomplete for you.

For the full details, see [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)